# Python os.listdir output only shows one file instead of all 6

Tags: python, image-classification, listdir

I am trying the [Loading Custom Image Dataset for Deep Learning Models](https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-custom-image-dataset-for-deep-learning-models-part-1-d64fa7aaeca6) tutorial by Renu Khandelwal from towardsdatascience.com. The code doesn't show any errors but the directory output shows
but I am getting the same wrong value concerning the directory.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras
import random
#from tensorflow.keras import layers, Dense, Input, InputLayer, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline

IMG_WIDTH=200
IMG_HEIGHT=200
img_folder='//Users//julie-anne.rosquin//Documents//leongrosse//Intel_images//seg_train//seg_train'
```

When I do a test, all of the files I'm looking for appear:

```
test = os.listdir(img_folder)
for file in test:
     if file != '.DS_Store':
            for image in os.listdir(os.path.join(file,image))
```

> forest buildings glacier street mountain sea

But when I try to apply it and get a dictionary, only the file forest appears :

```
def create_dataset(img_folder):
    img_data_array=[]
    class_name=[]
    for dir1 in os.listdir(img_folder):
        if dir1 != '.DS_Store':
            for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(img_folder, dir1)):
                image_path= os.path.join(img_folder, dir1,  file)
                image= cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                image=cv2.resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
                image=np.array(image)
                image = image.astype('float32')
                image /= 255 
                img_data_array.append(image)
                class_name.append(dir1)
        return img_data_array, class_name
# extract the image array and class name
img_data, class_name =create_dataset(r'//Users//julie-anne.rosquin//Documents//leongrosse//Intel_images//seg_train//seg_train')

target_dict={k: v for v, k in enumerate(np.unique(class_name))}
target_dict
```

> {'forest': 0}

Any idea on how to get the dictionary with all the files? I'm sure this is something obvious but I'm stuck on this and would appreciate some help! Many thanks

Comment: You `return` on the last line of the `for` loop.  That means that when the loop gets to the end of its first iteration, the `return` statement is hit and the function exits without getting the chance to go through the remaining iterations of the loop.  Instead, you should put that `return` statement outside the loop (de-indent it by one level).

Comment: Also, you might want to consider using `glob.glob`

Comment: @code-lukas how does glob.glob differ from os.listdir?

Comment: Functionally, it is similar, but it removes the need to have multiple `os.path.join` calls as `os.listdir` doesn't return the full path. It can make your code easier to read and less prone to error